# face warping / morphing - no framework around?

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I've been searching for quite a while and haven't found a real answer, yet, maybe I've got tomatoes on my eyes, but is there really no framework around for python / MATLAB which does a face warp / morph out of the box?

A framework, where I put in two images with the feature points (as seen in the example image) and it does the job?

[image: image warping]

Comment: In MATLAB, look at [`fitgeotrans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fitgeotrans.html) with the LocalWeightedMeanTransformation2D (`'lwm'`) transformation type.

Answer (score 0):

If calling an ImageMagick script from python works for you, take a look at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/shapemorph/index.php